# When changing the Win display lang, will builtin CLI tools params / stdout|stderr messages also change?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt, language, language-packs

I need to write a `CMD` script (other shells are not allowed / available) that will execute on multiple servers with different display languages.

When looking at an Windows built in tool, such as `logman.exe`, I have two unknowns:

1. Will `logman`'s CLI specification change based on Windows display language?

   - e.g. the 1st param to `logman.exe` is "`start|stop|...`". Will this turn into "`début|arrêtez|...`" when the language is French?
2. Will `logman`'s `stdout / stderr` messages change based on Windows display language?

   - e.g. when attempting to issue the stop command for a collector that is already stopped, `logman.exe` will say "`Error: Data Collector Set is not running.`". Will this turn into "`Erreur: Data Collector Set ne fonctionne pas.`" when the language is French?

**Please be specific to the command line tools built into Windows**. I'm expecting them to have a documented and uniform behavior in relation to the display language even though I was unable to find the appropriate Microsoft documentation via Google.

- For example, for the above issue #2, I was expecting to find some kind of string table containing "`Error: Data Collector Set is not running.`" with details on whether or not the string changes in various languages.

(3) Is it possible to force `CMD.EXE` and all its child processes to use English even though the Windows display language is something else?